# Integrate sentry in React Native project not working drop error log

Tags: react-native, crash-reports

I want to integrate sentry tool for react native project crash report so below is my code

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { Sentry,SentryLog } from 'react-native-sentry';
import Raven from 'raven-js';
Raven
    .config('https://****@sentry.io/1196569', {
        logLevel: SentryLog.Debug,
    })
    .install();
try {
    //doSomething(a[0])
} catch(e) {
    Raven.captureException(e)
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('RNCrashReport', () => App);
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    View
} from 'react-native';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>{Hello}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
    },
    instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
    },
});
```

In my **App.js**, I am not defining Text component in react-native package so it is an error but in my sentry dashboard error is not dropping so any idea, what I am missing for configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using Sentry but I didn't have to install *Raven*.

I see you've been reading the [JavaScript section](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/) which is why you've installed Raven. However, you should be looking at the [React Native section](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/react-native/).

I use the `react-native-sentry` package and to install it I simply use:

```
import { Sentry } from 'react-native-sentry'

Sentry.config('key').install();
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need for config is this

```
import { Sentry } from 'react-native-sentry';
Sentry.config(SENTRY_URL).install();
```

You can then use the methods listed in https://docs.sentry.io/clients/react-native/config/

To set your own key value pairs:

```
Sentry.setExtraContext({
     key: value, key: value,....
   });
```